# How to normalize two related options with OptionsResolver Component

Tags: php, symfony

I've the follows situation based on [OptionsResolver Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html):

- I have two options: `bar` and `foo`, both `null` by default.
- `bar` option accepts `B` value also.
- `foo` option accepts `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` values also.

Now, when these options are resolved, if `foo` option is equal to `A`, `bar` option must be changed to `B`, but I need too: if `foo` option is equal to `A` or `B` this must be changed to `C`.

---

I tried to implement that but the expected result is wrong:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'bar' => null,
    'foo' => null,
));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('bar', array(null, 'B'));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('foo', array(null, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));

$resolver->setNormalizer('bar', function (Options $options, $value) {
    if ('A' === $options['foo']) {
        return 'B';
    }

    return $value;
});

$resolver->setNormalizer('foo', function (Options $options, $value) {
    if ('A' === $value || 'B' === $value) {
        $value = 'C';
    }

    return $value;
});

$options = $resolver->resolve(array('foo' => 'A'));

var_dump($options);
```

this always returns:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"] => string(1) "C"
  ["bar"] => NULL  // wrong normalization, expected `B` value.
}
```

---

The problem is that `'A' === $options['foo']` statement in `bar` normalizer calls to `foo` normalizer ( i.e. `$options->offsetGet('foo')`) before to complete the condition, so for this test always checks `'A' === 'C'` and `bar` option does not normalized successfully.

**How to do it works?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a horrible workaround but it's the code that I implemented finally:

```
$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'foo' => null,  // <-- move to top to make sure to normalize first that bar
    'bar' => null,  // for internal use
));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('bar', array(null, 'B'));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('foo', array(null, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));

$bar = null;

$resolver->setNormalizer('foo', function (Options $options, $value) use (&$bar) {
    if ('A' === $value) {
        $bar = 'B';
    }

    if ('A' === $value || 'B' === $value) {
        $value = 'C';
    }

    return $value;
});

$resolver->setNormalizer('bar', function (Options $options, $value) use (&$bar) {
    return $bar;
});

$options = $resolver->resolve(array('foo' => 'A'));
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's not reliable to use this approach. You will always have to rely on the order of normalizing, and it's very easy to get lost.

I rather would use third option `baz` which will not be changed and will be like a source data for `bar` and `foo`.

```
$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'bar' => null,
    'foo' => null,
    'baz' => null,
));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('bar', array(null, 'B'));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('foo', array(null, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
$resolver->setAllowedValues('baz', array(null, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));

$resolver->setNormalizer('bar', function (Options $options, $value) {
    if ('A' === $options['baz']) {
        return 'B';
    }

    return $value;
});

$resolver->setNormalizer('foo', function (Options $options, $value) {
    if ('A' === $options['baz'] || 'B' === $options['baz']) {
        $value = 'C';
    } else {
        return $options['baz'];
    }
});

$options = $resolver->resolve(array('baz' => 'A'));
```

Comment: The second normalizer returns `null` when `$value = 'C'`, please fix that to accept the answer. Thanks @Dmitry.

Comment: Sorry, I found other solution to do that, thanks anyway ;)